# Can an armed door be opened from outside an airliner?

Tags: aircraft-design, emergency, evacuation

This is a continuation from [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12952/what-does-it-mean-for-a-door-to-be-armed), whereby it discussed the meaning and significance of an armed door.

Now, is it possible to open an armed door from outside, for example, if for some reason the passenger or crew are incapacitated, due to inhalation of poisonous gasses etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*This depends on the aircraft:*

**DC9, MD80, B727, B737**

On some (especially older model) aircraft doors such as the Boeing 737 for instance this is directly dangerous, since the slide is attached on the inside by hand with the means of a *girt bar* to the aircraft.

There is hence no way to open the door without the slide going off should it be armed. There is a helpful notice in red on the outside to "stand clear" when the red banner is crosses the window, the indication that it is armed. Judging by the space required and force the doors have, this is still most probably very dangerous idea that should not be used unless absolutely necessary.

[image: ![http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Aircraft_Door_B737_or_A320_family.JPG](door)]
[Source](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Aircraft_Door_B737_or_A320_family.JPG)

**Airbus, B757, B767, B777, MD11, E-Jets**

On more modern aircraft, this is safe: opening the door externally will push the arm handle to the disarmed position before proceeding to open it. This is for instance the case on all Airbus aircraft.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a26-IkTjn88) provides a nice example.

Comment: Nice explanation there and the video.. Does the Airbus have any mechanism to prevent opening of doors from outside, thinking from safety POV...

Comment: @Firee safety in what sense or scenario? Not that I know of...

Comment: @Firee. from a *safety* POV it is desirable that the door *can* be opened from outside. From a *security* POV there is the airport security staff.